# How do I enable autocomplete in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

1. Created file~/.my.cnf

```
[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

2. Restarted the daemon
3. Autocomplete does not work

Comment: That is a _client_ function; did you restart _it_?

Comment: And, hit TAB twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I enable autocomplete in MariaDB?

You don't need to enable it..

> **Using mysql**
>
> The command to use mysql and the general syntax is:
>
> `mysql <options>`
>
> **Options**
>
> mysql supports the following options:

--auto-rehash

> Enable automatic rehashing. **This option is on by default, which
>   enables database, table, and column name completion**.
>   ...
>   ...
>   To complete a name, enter the first part and press Tab. **If the name is unambiguous, mysql completes it.** Otherwise, you can press Tab again to see the possible names that begin with what you have typed so far. **Completion does not occur if there is no default database.**

see the [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql-command-line-client/)

Comment: Thank you for '...Completion does not occur if there is no default database.'.

Comment: "Completion does not occur if there is no default database.'." @irk2adm it was a educated guess to also copy and paste that part and make it bold because i had a feeling that might be your problem.